# randomly reassign group membership with condition

Tags: r, random, group-by, sample

I have the following table:

| name | group |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 2 |
| d | 2 |
| e | 3 |
| f | 3 |

and I want to randomly re-assign the group membership by (i) making sure that the names will *not* be assigned to same group, and (ii) the probability of the group membership will remain the same. Also, I am trying to (iii) avoid all the names under the same group to be assigned to the same new group. In essence I want to achieve something like this:

| name | group | new.group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 2 |
| b | 1 | 3 |
| c | 2 | 1 |
| d | 2 | 3 |
| e | 3 | 1 |
| f | 3 | 2 |

How do I do this in `R`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all the restrictions, this is barely shuffling anymore: You could use the modulo operator.

```
df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(new_group = (2 + row_number() + group) %% 3 + 1)

  name  group new_group
  <chr> <int>     <dbl>
1 a         1         2
2 b         1         3
3 c         2         3
4 d         2         1
5 e         3         1
6 f         3         2
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `sample` + `setdiff`

```
transform(
  df,
  new.group = ave(group, group, FUN = function(x) sample(setdiff(group, x),length(x)))
)
```

gives

```
  name group new.group
1    a     1         2
2    b     1         3
3    c     2         1
4    d     2         3
5    e     3         1
6    f     3         2
```

## Data

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(name = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), group = c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
-6L))
```